# Delegate between two UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Is it possible to delegate between two UICollectionViews? I tried to make my delegate, but I can't because UICollectionView already have its own delegator.

If it is possible, how to do that?

EDIT:

I have two UICollectionViews and I want them to communicate.
If you select item in first one, then the second one (in his own class) changes its data.

Example:

```
// UICollectionViewOne    
...
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
    getThings(url: viewModel.type[indexPath.row]){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.uiCollectionViewTwo.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #2:

Each UICollectionViews have **its own class**. UIViewController also has its own class.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Would you mind sharing an example of what you'd want (if it were possible)?

Comment: ```if collectionView.tag == first_collectionView { //do something self.secondCollectionCiew.reloadData()}```

Comment: `if collectionView == uiCollectionViewOne { //do the thing on collectionTwo } else if collectionview == uiCollectionviewTwo { //do the thing on collectionViewone }`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to reload specific collection view when you have more than one.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var firstCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var secondollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // MARK: - View life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add delegates
        firstCollectionView.delegate = self
        secondollectionView.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - Methods

    private func reloadFirstCollectionViewData() {
        // TODO:
        // Manage first collection view data source
        // Reload second collection or collection view at index path
        // Ex. firstCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])
    }

    private func reloadSecondCollectionViewData() {
        // TODO:
        // Manage second collection view data source
        // Reload second collection or collection view at index path
        // Ex. secondollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == firstCollectionView {
            // Reload second collection view
            reloadSecondCollectionViewData()
        } else if collectionView == secondollectionView {
            // Reload first collection view
            reloadFirstCollectionViewData()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to go one mile away, separate delegates and data sources into a new file/object to make the view controller thinner! Here is a great article from Paul Hudson:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/86/how-to-move-data-sources-and-delegates-out-of-your-view-controllers

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but my task is to separate Controller and Controllers to make Controller as simple as possible.

Comment: I would not recommend splitting this extension outside of the view controller class. Can you please add more code about what your Controller for the collection view looks like?

Comment: I think this is the best approach from what I understood that you are trying to achieve. It will take some time to understand, but it's worth doing it. Once you achieve it, you will do it all the time for other view controllers. See article:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/86/how-to-move-data-sources-and-delegates-out-of-your-view-controllers

Comment: You can use then a delegate pattern between the two delegate to ask the other one to reloads it collectionView? But that wasn't in your question.